# Square popup is coming while refreshing the page or switching the router with loading gif

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

> Whenever we are loading the page or switching the router then we are
> showing the loader(loading gif ) in web page application so loading
> gif is coming with shadow popup . Not able to understand how to remove
> it and how to handle it?

**Chrome Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build)(64-bit)**

**Loading Gif Details:**

- Dimension: 193X 192
- Width/Height: 193/192 pixels
- Bit Depth: 8
- Item Type: GIF
- File Size: 170KB

[image: Gif is coming with shadow]

[image: Popup shadow is coming with gif]

```js
import React from 'react';
import loadingGif from '../../img/loader.gif';

const Loader = (props) => {
  return (
    props.showLoader ? <div className="modal-backdrop modal-backdrop-loader" style={{ paddingTop: '0'}}>
      <img src={loadingGif} alt="Loading. Please wait!" style={{ top: '50%', left: '50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', position: 'fixed', height: '75px', width: '75px'}} />
    </div> : ""
  );
}
export default Loader;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal is coming from the `div` around the `img`:

```
<div className="modal-backdrop modal-backdrop-loader" style={{ paddingTop: '0'}}>
```

If you have the Bootstrap CSS file loaded then the `modal-backdrop` class has some styles attached to it:

```css
.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

That creates a black background that appears on top of other content and is the full width and full height of the window.
[Bootstrap Modal Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options)

---

It's up to you how you want to handle this.  Do you sometimes want to show the backdrop?  Should `showBackdrop` be a prop?  How do you want to style the container when there is no backdrop?

```js
// some random gif to use as a placeholder
const loadingGif =
  "https://icon-library.net/images/spinner-icon-gif/spinner-icon-gif-28.jpg";

// just the spinner
const Loader = ({ showLoader = true }) => {
  return showLoader ? (
    <img
      src={loadingGif}
      alt="Loading. Please wait!"
      style={{
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        position: "fixed",
        height: "75px",
        width: "75px"
      }}
    />
  ) : null;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Loader showLoader={true} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thanks, But i need that black screen. And if i am removing the <img> tag then no popup shadow is coming.

Comment: I thought the question was asking how to remove the black screen.  What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: I removed 'modal-backdrop' class and add another class now it is working fine . Thanks!!!

Comment: Actually, ever since I got a new laptop form the organization, I am having this problem . Previously it was working fine with old laptop, so is there any laptop or Chrome configuration problem? Please help me out this.

Comment: Is class ".modal-backdrop" behave differently in different laptop or Chrome configuration?

Comment: I think so . In my previous laptop it was working fine but current laptop it is showing popup shadow.